# How do I specify what mData in AudioBuffer in the CoreAudio framework should represent?

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-audio

How do I initialize the CoreAudio framework such that I know what the values in mData represent?  As per a previous reply I had gotten, it seems these values can represent 4 byte floats, 4 byte signed integers etc.  But what API would I use to specify what exactly I want these values to represent?

Answer (score 1):

Call AudioUnitSetProperty() on your Audio Unit with the kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat AudioUnitPropertyID , and with the appropriate AudioStreamBasicDescription struct fields (including mFormatID, mFormatFlags, mBitsPerChannel, and etc.) filled in with your desired data type (int/float, signed, bits, endianness, etc.)  Do this before starting the Audio Unit.

Check the result code and/or read back the property to see if your desired setting succeeded or not.

See Apple's Audio Unit Properties Reference and Audio Unit Component Services Reference documents for details.

Comment: Thanks.  What is the default set to?